# correct way to implement operator== in .cpp file

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

i have a class which needs to implement the operator== and return type of it is bool. I'm not sure is below code the correct way to implement it.

//MyTest.hpp file

```
class Test {
public:

    Test();
    virtual ~Test();

    int x,y;

    bool operator==(const Test &v);

};

// MyTest.cpp file

bool Test::operator==(const Test &v) {
    return (x== v.x) && (y==v.y);
}
```

even though the code compiles is this standard way to implement we need to use template.
Should i use template way of implementation like below code :

```
template <class T>
bool operator==(const T &v);
```

Comment: To use a template is not the standard way.

Comment: Have you taken a look at http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/templates/ ?

Comment: @juanchopanza - i have edited sample code..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have mentioned, using a template without any reason to do so is neither standard nor recommended. However assuming you want `operator==` to be more like one of the default comparison operators you should either mark it `const` (otherwise you cannot compare two `const Test`) like so

```
class Test {
public:
    Test();
    virtual ~Test();

    int x,y;

    bool operator==(const Test &v) const;
};

// MyTest.cpp file

bool Test::operator==(const Test &v) const {
    return (x== v.x) && (y==v.y);
}
```

, or make it a free function (in the same namespace for ADL) taking two `const Test &` (preferred) like so

```
class Test {
public:
    Test();
    virtual ~Test();

    int x,y;
};

bool operator==(const Test &a, const Test &b);

// MyTest.cpp file

bool operator==(const Test &a, const Test &b) {
    return (a.x==b.x) && (a.y==b.y);
}
```

If any access to private members is required the free function can always be marked `friend`. In simple cases such as the one in this example it can be advantageous to furthermore define it in the header and marking it `inline`.

Answer (score 5):

Don't use templates unless you need to. Does it make sense for `Test` to be comparable with *any type*? I doubt so.

Also there's no "Standard way" because the standard does not impose a strict way to implement `operator==` (I think it mentions something on the return type, but I doubt it actually enforces anything).

It's a good idea to make it return a `bool` and make it does what people expect it does (compare the two objects in a meaningful way).

And finally, you should mark your current one `const`:

```
bool operator==(const Test &v) const;
```

Unless it actually modifies the invoking object, which is definitely something you don't want it to do.

Comment: Incidentally, it is probably a good idea to implement `operator!=` too.

Comment: @MatteoItalia, yes. Possibly in terms of `operator==`. Like `bool operator!=(T const& a, T const& b) { return !(a == b); }`.

Answer (score 1):

Please do not use templates matching anything:

```
template <class T>
bool operator==(const T &, const T &);
```

That one will put you in all kinds of trouble !

Comment: ok..i have edited the code now .. which returns the bool value.

Comment: @user1291401 The comment is at the wrong spot